# How do I migrate existing CharField with data to IntegerField in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite, migration

I have some models with CharFields in in my models.py.

e.g.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    item_port = models.CharField(max_length=50)`
```

I have realised that this was a little stupid for a port and changed them all to IntegerFields as follows:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    item_port = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

I am using sqlite3 in my local dev system and a MySQL type database for deployment.  Typically, I manufacture migrations for a new docker instance when deploying from scratch using:

`python manage.py makemigrations`
and
`python manage.py migrate`

However, I also have a record of all migrations made to my sqlite3 db in git for reference purposes.

My main question is, can I get away with simply doing a makemigrations/migrate from CharField to IntegerField with existing data in the database (which on client sites will be a MySQL type database OR do I need to do something like this manually?:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Thanks very much.

Comment: I believe that strings like `'8080'` will be converted to integers like `8080` when you change from a `CharField` to an `IntegerField`. However you might have problem with other strings. In particular you might need a data migration to convert the empty string `''` to `None` (in which case you'd need another migration to change the `CharField` to `null=True`). Make sure you test MySQL as well as sqlite - don't assume they will behave the same way.

Comment: for this type of migrations when data change is required you would have to go for the data-migrations as above...

Comment: According to the official source, you cannot specifically change a text field to an integer field and assume Django migrations system can handle that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/migration-operations/#alterfield

Answer (score 1):

If you notice that `item_port` should be a `IntergerField` not a `CharField` you can run

```
./manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto --update
```

Refering to the South documentation [Advanced Commands and Data Migrations](http://south.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html)

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I'm afraid I chose to move back to Django's migration system a while back as South doesn't meet my needs.